# jQuery Post , then Access AngularJS $scope

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ajaxq

In our AngularJS app, we need to use jQuery to AJAX POST data to a back end. We can't use $http as it doesn't format the object in a way our back end needs it. jQuery does.

I am trying to set a $scope variable once the jQuery POST is done, but can't access $scope.

```
 $scope.submit = function () {
        $scope.isSubmitting = true;
        $.post("DoStuff",{ createmodel: $scope.model })
            .then(function(result) {
                ///THIS FAILS TO DO ANYTHING
                $scope.isSubmitting = false;
            });

    };
```

How do I access $scope in the jQuery POST after it comes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails to do anything because jQuery does not inform Angular that a scope variable has changed. You can simply achieve this by adding `$scope.$apply()`

In your case the solution is

```
$scope.isSubmitting = false;
$scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put this inside of a $scope.$apply

```
$scope.apply(function(){
   $scope.isSubmitting = false;
})
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply